# RxJs map passes an array instead of one element of an array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-runner

I have this service which retrieves data from the server

```
export class SiteService {

  API_URL = '/sites';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get<Site[]>(this.API_URL).pipe(
      map((site: Site) => {
        console.log('---site', site);
        return new Site().deserialize(site);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

My data is currently coming from a mocking test via `flush` from testBed and HttpTestingCotroller.
Here is what I pass

```
const dummySites = [
        {
          path: 'https://example.com/img1.img',
          siteLink: 'http://example1.com',
          features: [
            'feature 1',
            'feature 2',
            'feature 3'
          ]
        },
        {
          path: 'https://example.com/img2.img',
          siteLink: 'http://example2.com',
          features: [
            'feature 1',
            'feature 2',
            'feature 3'
          ]
        }
      ];
```

However at the end when I try to map through this array of data I get a strange behaviour of `map`. In the code there is a `console.log` to check what comes into the function and there is what it is
[image]
By some reason it passes not an element of an array but the whole array what breaks me the entire logic in the next steps.

Comment: That's because it's `map` on the Observable-- it's used to transform the `Observable` value. If You also want to transform each item within the array, you will *also* need to call `.map` on the array, probably from inside the Obervable map

Comment: What do you mean... That's what I found on the site https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Comment: The prior comment is correct - map is applied to the stream of values emitted by the Observable, in this case each value is an array of sites.

Comment: In that example, the Observable will separately emit each value. So if you were to subscribe, it would first call subscribe with 1, then with 2 etc etc. In your code, it will only emit one value, and that value will be an array

Comment: Every example I look at in the Internet works although it's written in my way...

Comment: The first response is correct. The example you site, is making a stream of events out of an array. In your code, each element in the stream of events is an array...

Comment: Well... That worked however I still don't understand how... Unfortunately your explanation is a bit overwhelming for me. Please, post your answer I'll check it as a right one. Also, I still don't understand why in the Internet that works (at least it's explained that way) when it's mapped once

Comment: @Sergey Okay, I've added an answer below and tried to provide a bit more explanation. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable`s are designed to emit a stream of values. Some things like `http` will only emit one value, but some will emit several

The rxjs `map` operator is designed to transform each value that is emitted by the `Observable`. Your `Observable` originates from an HTTP request, so it will only ever emit one value, which in this case will be an array. That means the value that is passed into `map` is the array, not each value within the array.

If you also want to transform each item within the array, you can use the `map` function that belongs to the array as well

```
  getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get<Site[]>(this.API_URL).pipe(
      map((site: Site[]) => {
        console.log('---site', site);
        return site.map((s) => new Site().deserialize(s));
      })
    );
  }
```